# My LAMP server is always running- isn't this a waste of resources?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web, lamp

On my Windows and Mac boxes, the WAMP and MAMP servers (respectively) are started and stopped manually, but on my Linux box the LAMP stack is always available without the need for starting and stopping.

Isn't this a waste of resources?

Comment: Do you think Wamp/Lamp are mining bitcoins?

Comment: Just prevent them from autostarting http://superuser.com/questions/203827/how-do-i-prevent-linux-services-from-auto-starting

Comment: If you're really worried about that, perhaps you should unplug your server until you know a request is coming in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it kinda is :)

Anyway, I expect it to go to "sleep" when not in use, so it wouldnt use much resources (except maybe the database)

Also, on all linux distros, you have commands to start and stop these just as you have on Windows and Macs

Answer (score 0):

You can start or stop it using the follwing command 
"sudo service apache2 stop" assuming you are using Debian based distribution like Ubuntu or mint , it works also for much more distributions
, and "sudo service apache2 start" to start the service , however it is not resource consuming as apache do adapt its CPU usage depending on the traffic in case of no traffic you will have an extremely low CPU usage .
You can also change what services to start or stop in Linux , the method changes from one distribution to another 
Please state you Linux distro

Comment: check out this post http://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services